# How to pass additional arguments to scipy.optimize.newton_krylov?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

So I'm trying to find `"k"`  which satisfies the equation

```
F(k,u,v,w) = 0
```

and u, v, and w are extra parameters.  I've been trying to solve it using newton_krylov (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton_krylov.html), which will solve the system numerically based on a guess for **`k`**, but there does not appear to be a way to include the other parameters.

My trouble is that I need to pass **`F`** the additional arguments, but there does not appear to be a way to pass them to **`F`**.  Is there a way to pass them that I don't know about? or is there a hack I can do to make it work?

Also if there is a more appropriate function for this situation that would be cool too.

Comment: One assumes you could write a function F(k) that knew about u, v, and w. F(k) could either be a method of a class that include ways to set and get the other parameters, or could use u, v, and w out of a namespace defined by you that your F(k) has access to, or (last choice) use global...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass `F` wrapped in lambda function into `newton_krylov`, something like this:

```
newton_krylov(lambda k:F(k,1,2,3), ... )
```